# Installing mod_mono for ASP.NET on MacOSX Leopard

Tags: macos, mono, mod-mono

I'm trying to get mod_mono built and installed so I can start learning and working with  ASP.NET on my Mac.  My machine is running Mac OSX Leopard 10.5.7.

The mono site (http://www.mono-project.com) says I need to install
xsp, mono and mod_mono.

Mono is installed and working.
xsp built and installed fine.

My configure output for mod_mono is:

Configuration summary for mod_mono

- Installation prefix = /usr/local
- Apache version = 2.2
- Apache modules directory = /usr/libexec/apache2
- apxs = /usr/sbin/apxs
- apr-config = /usr/bin/apr-1-config
- apu-config = /usr/bin/apu-1-config
- CFLAGS = -64 -I/usr/include/apache2    -I/usr/include/apr-1    -I/usr/include/apr-1
- Verbose logging (debug) = no
- GCOV options used = no
- Profiling enabled = no
- mono prefix = /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.4.2.2
- Default MonoApplicationsConfigDir = /private/etc/apache2/mod-mono-applications

...which looks ok, as far as I can tell. When I try to make mod_mono, however,
I get the following error:

`gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -64 -I/usr/include/apache2 -I/usr/include/apr-1
 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -64 -I/usr/include/apache2 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -I/usr/include/apache2
 -64 -I/usr/include/apache2 -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -no-cpp-precomp -64
 -I/usr/include/apache2 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -DDARWIN <br>-DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK
 -no-cpp-precomp -I/usr/include/apr-1 -Wall
 -DDFLT_MONO_CONFIG_DIR=\"/private/etc/apache2/mod-mono-applications\"
 -I/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.4.2.2/include/glib-2.0
 -I/Library/Frameworks<br>/Mono.framework/Versions/2.4.2.2/lib/glib-2.0/include -64
 -I/usr/include/apache2 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -MT mod_mono_la-mod_mono.lo -MD
 -MP -MF .deps/mod_mono_la-mod_mono.Tpo -c mod_mono.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o
 .libs/mod_mono_la-mod_mono.o`

```
mod_mono.c: In function ‘fork_mod_mono_server’:
mod_mono.c:1775: error: ‘SIGPWR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_mono.c:1775: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
mod_mono.c:1775: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[1]: *** [mod_mono_la-mod_mono.lo] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Has anyone seen/fixed this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This came up on Mono IRC yesterday, and supposedly it can be fixed by commenting out line 1775 in mod_mono.c.